# Duplicate Id issue

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have master detail from in which I have one identity column which I am getting the max value and increment and the same id I am referring to my detail table using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC.

It's working fine until unless if two at the same time inserting record so before update the max value is same and it gives me duplicate ID issue.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Get the database to calculate the ID instead, using the built in facilities it has for it. Don't do select max+1 yourself

Answer (score 0):

Your key column should use the attribute [[DatabaseGenerated]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8), ideally with the value [DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.8).

Do not reinvent the wheel when it is already round and works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have master detail table and I have to refer the ID column value to detail table so I am generating ID value manually. I am using entity framework.

Comment: When I am using identity column it will generate automatic value and how can i refer that value in my detail table?

Comment: If you have the relationship defined, then you insert entities rather than worrying about what IDs they have. EF will take care of that itself.

Comment: It mean if i have master detail table with primary and foreign key relation It will automatically refer my primary key id to detail table?